# vimeo html5 edit CSS

Tags: jquery, css, html, vimeo

Is it possible to edit vimeo's HTML CSS attributes? I have an autoplaying video and no need for the play button.

I'd like to edit this class.

```
.a.l .b .as {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin: -2em 0 0 -3.25em;
float: none;
z-index: 3;
```

}

Id would like to add a `display:none;` to this class.

Building on what Jonathan Sampson says. Is this possible:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("iframe#vim").contents().find('.as.av').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML5 video is currently delivered through an `iframe`, so you can't touch the button:

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/7403673" 
        width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" 
        webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

A year ago the Vimeo staff spoke out defending their decision to *not* allow users to hide the play/pause button, suggesting it creates a *bad user experience*: http://vimeo.com/forums/topic:31015

Comment: @uriah No, not unless the `iframe` is being loaded from your domain - which is not the case for Vimeo videos.